# jQuery - Remove select list values

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery code that checks the current page title and adds it as the selected value to a select list. The code is:

```
function displayVals() {
  var pgTitle = $('h1').val();
}

$('select').change(displayVals);
displayVals();
```

Is there a way to remove the other values from the select list that are not selected?

Comment: What's the point of having drop down with only one option that is always selected??

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$("select option:selected"))
    $(this).remove();
});
```

that it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$("#sel1").change(function(){
    var options = $(this).find("option");
    var selectedOpt = options.filter(":selected");
    options.remove();
    $(this).append(selectedOpt);
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BrvNG/)